# Polite way to convey something instead of using YOU

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction, politeness

> Last time **you** took 80% share, so I think at least 70% should be mine this time.

Is there a more polite way to say this? I feel the use of the word **you** sounds like I am blaming someone. Not sure if that is the actual case.

How else could I put this? The context here is the share of the money.

Comment: In some contexts it's considered "rude" to use the female third person singular pronoun ***she*** rather than a woman's name (if and *only* if she's actually *present*, but not necessarily joining in the conversation). I never heard of anything similar in relation to the ***second*** person singular. But if it bothers ***you***, you could just rephrase to *Last time **I only got** a 20% share, so I think at least 70% should be mine this time.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers The rephrasing sounds good. So just to confirm once again, the use of `you` is not at all rude here, correct? Probably I am overthinking here

Comment: Well, obviously your specific context is one where the speaker is *complaining* to the addressee, which implies the addressee must be capable of doing something to affect the relative share each of them get *this* time. So by further implication *it's the other guy's fault* that the speaker got such a poor payout *last* time. That's the only reason there might be anything rude about the conversation - it sounds like one guy is screwing the other, who is therefore complaining.

Answer (score 2):

Using "you" is perfectly fine. It does not always imply blaming someone. I might rephrase your sentence a little:

> Last time you had 80% of the shares. Perhaps this time I take at least 70?

Answer (score 1):

It's not the "you" that sounds rude, it's the verb "took" which could imply  the person had earned the shares, money, profits etc. unfairly. Telling someone they "took" something can have an accusatory tone.

Replace "took" with *give* in the passive voice.

- *Last time you **were given** 80% share, so I think at least 70% should be mine this time*.

> **take**
> 1.5 Dispossess someone of (something); steal or illicitly remove.
>
> ‘People using cash machines are being warned to be on the alert, after four customers had their cash cards taken.’
>
> [*Lexico*](https://www.lexico.com/definition/take)

Comment: My approach to toning down the "reproachful" implications of the context was to avoid any reference to ***your*** share by recasting to *Last time **I only got** a 20% share, so I think at least 70% should be mine this time* (avoiding any reference to ***you***, who were by implication responsible for previous unfairness). But your idea of casting ***you*** into the passive is equally good (unless it doesn't make sense because the addressee was the only person involved in deciding what proportion of the total he would "give" ***to himself***).

Comment: Or simply "received" instead of "took".

Comment: Lots of alternatives I agree, the point I was making that the verb "took" can be misconstrued.